# Time complexity of finding a fixed-size matching in a hypergraph

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

Define a size $k$ matching in a hypergraph $H = (V,E)$ to be a collection of $k$ pairwise disjoint edges in $E$. Is anyone aware of the (best-known) time complexity of finding, for fixed $k$, a size $k$ matching in an arbitrary hypergraph? I can find plenty of references for the problem with respect to graphs, but not hypergraphs.

Comment: Since the problem of deciding whether there  exists a 3-dimensional matching of size $\geq k$ is NP-complete, then the above problem is no easier, I think.

Comment: Let $M=\{\langle H,k\rangle \mid \text{ there is a matching of size }k\text{ in a hypergraph H}\}$. Let $M_k=\{\langle H\rangle \mid \text{ there is a matching of size }k\text{ in a hypergraph H}\}$. Are you asking about each $M_k$ for $k=2,3,\cdots$ or about $M$?